# Getting the current tokenizer in Monaco

Tags: javascript, monaco-editor

Is it possible to get the current tokenizer of a custom language in monaco so I can edit it dynamically instead of adding it into the tokenizer before starting the program?

So for example I have the basic constants in my tokenizer

```js
constants: [
    "game"
],
```

but say I needed to add another one whilst everything is running, (please note my workspace is split into seperate files and folder)

Comment: no, not via the public api - but you could try going inside the black box.. what maybe to search for: the lexer is called "monarch" and its compiled and maybe take a look at `InspectTokens`